# Unable to open file for reading [ file link ] laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

I am trying to send a mail to multiple recipients with an attachment of file URL , but while hitting the api in postman it's throwing an error unable to open file for reading [ file link ] , but while I am copying file link and opens in browser it's opening perfectly .

I have checked the file permission also and referred to some of the answers on Stackoverflow but nothing helped me, please help me as soon as possible.

[image]

```
        $file_name = 'TimeActivityReport' . "_" . time() . '.pdf';
        $storage_path = 'public/TimeActivityReport';
        // $storage_path = public_path();
        
        $filePath = $storage_path . '/' . $file_name;
        // return $filePath;
        $exl = Excel::store(new TimeActivityReportExport($all_total_values,$data,$date_totals), $filePath);
        if($exl)
        {
        $fileurl = asset('storage/TimeActivityReport').'/'.$file_name;
        // return $fileurl;
        }
// return $fileurl;
       return Mail::send([], $emails, function($message)use($fileurl,$emails) {
            $message->to($emails,'hello')
            ->subject('test')
            ->attach($fileurl,[
                'as' => 'checkname.pdf', 
                'mime' => 'application/pdf'
            ])
            ->setBody('check');
            });
```

Comment: try dd( file_exists(asset('storage/TimeActivityReport/YOUR_FILE_NAME'))); and see what you get?

Comment: it's showing false ,but file is exist inside 'storage/app/public/TimeActivityReport/file_name'

Comment: Try change this asset('storage/TimeActivityReport') to asset('TimeActivityReport/'.$file_name) and dd() it again. its a problem with your url, also what do you get if you dd(asset('TimeActivityReport/'.$file_name));

Comment: it's again showing false

Comment: assets gives you an url with `http`, you need to put a system directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this I tested it on my end and it returned the file

```
Storage::get('./public/TimeActivityReport/'.$file_name);
```

You can also test if the file exists using:

```
Storage::disk('local')->exists('public/TimeActivityReport/'.$file_name);
```

To attach try:

```
$fileurl = Storage::path('public/TimeActivityReport/'.$file_name);
```

resource [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#retrieving-files)

Comment: i tried this and it's returning the file but , the query is , while attaching the file url to attach() method during sending mail it's showing error that unable to open file for reading

Comment: biggest diff is i replaced 'storage/' with 'public/'

Comment: Thank you soo much , finally $fileurl = Storage::path('public/TimeActivityReport/'.$file_name); this worked for me

thank you again

Comment: Its a pleasure just remember to mark as answer if this was the answer @kishanmaharana